# Run Oracle Java Embedded Suite 7.0 (ARM Linux version) on rooted Android

Tags: java, linux, arm

My goal is to run a Tomcat web server on my phone, but running any Java app would be fine. It seems that the Oracle Java Embedded Suite 7.0 is a regular Java SE that can be run on ARM devices (disclaimer, I've never used Java Embedded before).

I've copied it to my phone via ADB, but when I try to run the java executable it says it can't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have a classical Java Runtime Environment (JRE) to run Java applications. It doesn't confirm to any of Java Micro / Standard / Enterprise editions, meaning it doesn't need to have `java` executable or any other necessary libraries. Because of this, you can't just push and run Java application which otherwise *runs anywhere*.

If you want to run a web server on your Android phone, you can try [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/). If you want to run a normal Java application on Android, then you need to port it using [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and [reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) which might not be trivial.

Pushing Java SE Embedded to an Android phone also wouldn't work because as its [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/se-embeddocs/index.html) lists, you at least need to have **glibc 2.9 or higher** to run it which Android stack doesn't provide.

Comment: I'm aware that the android vm is not a regular Java VM. That's why I was asking about installing this Java Embedded Suite.

Comment: So it's not straightforward as I was hoping, right? It's possible to ditch Android and install some Debian or flavor of Linux into the phone, with the needed package to make JES7 work, but that would defeat the idea of still having the phone fully functional. Therefore I would need to install glibc to make JES7 work, and then check the requirements for glibc, and so on.